# Improve the effeciency of query processing in a improved version of star schema

Tags: data-mining

I have a fact table , measure table and and connected to them are dimension tables. It is just a slight modification to star schema. But know as the no of joins are increasing due to introduction of measure table the query processing time is increased. Can any one suggest some approach to improve efficiency of query processing? Like adding some bridges between diemensions etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store aggregated version of your data by frequently used dimensions, so that you can leave them out of joins that need to run faster.